# Idle Connection Timeout in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to set Idle Connection Timeout in mongoose ?
Am trying like the one below.

```
mongoose.createConnection(IP:port/{server:{"maxIdleTimeMS":1800000}})
```

But the above code doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

this option called connectTimeoutMS not maxIdleTimeMS and it is a socket option. this is a sample code that work :

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/myDb';
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 1800000}}};
 mongoose.createConnection(uri, options, function (err) {
     if (!err){
    console.log("Connection successful");}
 });
```

Good luck

Comment: If a connection stays idle for more than 5 minutes , i dont want the application to hold the connection.But the above code doesnt return the connection to pool.

Comment: db.serverStatus().connections  still shows me that 5 connections are active

Comment: poolSize connections are opened to the db when you connect. the default is 5,you can adjust the pool size using your connection option as follows:
var options = { server: {**poolSize: 10**, socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 1800000}}};